# PostScript viewer for iPad

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation

Are there any Postscript (.ps) viewers for iPad?

Secondly, having used [Okular](http://okular.kde.org) on Linux that can read .ps, .pdf and .djvu files, is there anything that does all three or more?

Finally, I am looking for a plain interface rather than the interface from such items as iBooks.

Thanks a lot!